# how to copy from one column to another but with different format

Tags: sql, copy

I hv a table like this:-

```
Item            Model           Remarks 
-----------------------------------------
A               10022009
B               10032006
C               05081997
```

I need to copy the info from "Model" to "Remarks" with the following format:-

```
Item            Model          Remarks 
-----------------------------------------
A               10022009       20090210
B               10032006       20060310
C               05081997       19970805
```

Thanks

Comment: What database and version? What is the column type? char(8)?

Comment: text though it looks like date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update the_table set remarks = 
   substr(model, 5, 4) || substr(model, 3, 2) || substr (model, 1, 2)
```

You could also use date parsing / formatting functions instead of string operations.

Comment: I hv tried with 1 row & it works. However, when I tried with 150k rows, it prompted with 'Character in CAST argument not valid". What shd I do now ?

Comment: You probably have some rows with invalid or missing data. You may need to add `where model is not null` or something similar.